# Change Start-up Form in Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have two forms in my Delphi Project. Namely:

```
FrmMain_u.pas
FrmLogIn_u.pas
```

When I run the Delphi Project, the `FrmMain_u` form is displayed. How will I change the start up form from `FrmMain_u` to `FrmLogIn_u`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From IDE:

menu Project->Options (the last item)
Select "Forms" item

You can find the auto-create forms.
The first form "auto-create" is the startup form.

Comment: Another option is to edit the dpr file. Here is located the code that creates the actual forms.